# When does remove implies removal of parents and siblings?

Tags: bazaar

Compare this interaction:

```
C:\MyRepo\MyBranch>bzr stat
unknown:
  File.txt
  Pippo.txt
  a/

C:\MyRepo\MyBranch>bzr add a
adding a
adding a/Pluto.txt
adding a/Topolino.txt

C:\MyRepo\MyBranch>bzr remove a/Pluto.txt --keep
removed a/Pluto.txt
```

Against this one:

```
C:\MyRepo\MyBranch>bzr stat
unknown:
  File.txt
  Pippo.txt
  a/

C:\MyRepo\MyBranch>bzr add a
adding a
adding a/Pluto.txt
adding a/Topolino.txt

C:\MyRepo\MyBranch>bzr remove a/Pluto.txt --keep --new
removed a/Topolino.txt
removed a/Pluto.txt
removed a
```

The only difference is the inclusion of option **--new** in the second one. The effect of **--new** is that also the siblings and parents of **Pluto.txt** are unversioned.

Consider also this example, in which also siblings of directory **a** are added:

```
C:\MyRepo\MyBranch>bzr stat
unknown:
  File.txt
  Pippo.txt
  a/

C:\MyRepo\MyBranch>bzr add
adding File.txt
adding Pippo.txt
adding a
adding a/Pluto.txt
adding a/Topolino.txt

C:\MyRepo\MyBranch>bzr remove a/Pluto.txt --keep --new
removed a/Topolino.txt
removed a/Pluto.txt
removed a
```

Again, **remove** with **--new** unversions the entire **a** directory, but not its siblings **File.txt** and **Pippo.txt** (showing that the **remove** command is still operating on **a** but it is unversioning too much).

**Why Bazaar is behaving like this?** Am I missing something?

Comment: Looks like a bug. I think it's *wrong* to remove the parent directory. Better to ask on https://answers.launchpad.net/bazaar or on http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I asked on launchpad.